# How to access MySQL database on docker from Spring application on Docker?

Tags: java, mysql, docker

I have a Spring Boot + MySQL application which cannot start in docker environment (manually it runs with no errors, but I have to change the **application.properties**)

So first I launch the MySQL in docker with these command:

```
docker run -p 3307:3306 --name mysqldb -e MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD=root -e MYSQL_DATABASE=exp mysql
```

And here it is the docker containers list:

```
CONTAINER ID   IMAGE     COMMAND                  CREATED          STATUS          PORTS                                                  NAMES
0cc5c690fb7e   mysql     "docker-entrypoint.s…"   30 seconds ago   Up 30 seconds   33060/tcp, 0.0.0.0:3307->3306/tcp, :::3307->3306/tcp   mysqldb
```

[This is screenshot of server connection settings for the database](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nn1ef.png)

When the database is running, I launch the Spring app with following commands in terminal:

```
docker run -p 9090:8080 --name exp --net spring-net -e MYSQL_HOST=mysqldb -e MYSQL_USER=root -e MYSQL_PASSWORD=root -e MYSQL_PORT=3306 exp
```

As you can see, I used the docker network which is connected to **mysqldb** with following command `docker network connect spring-net mysqldb`

Here are the **application.properies** settings:

```
spring.jpa.properties.hibernate.dialect=org.hibernate.dialect.MySQL5Dialect
spring.jpa.hibernate.naming-strategy=org.hibernate.cfg.ImprovedNamingStrategy
spring.jpa.properties.hibernate.ddl-auto=update
spring.jpa.properties.hibernate.show-sql=true

spring.datasource.url=jdbc:mysql://mysqldb:3307/exp?verifyServerCertificate=true&useSSL=false&serverTimezone=UTC&useLegacyDatetimeCode=false
spring.datasource.driverClassName=com.mysql.cj.jdbc.Driver
spring.datasource.username=root
spring.datasource.password=root
spring.datasource.initialization-mode=always
spring.datasource.validationQuery=SELECT 1
spring.datasource.testWhileIdle=true
spring.server.port=8080
spring.server.compression.enabled=true
spring.jpa.database-platform=org.hibernate.dialect.H2Dialect
spring.jpa.hibernate.ddl-auto=update
spring.jpa.properties.hibernate.format_sql=true
```

When I try to start this, the application cannot find the mysqldb, here is the error from console:

```
Caused by: java.net.UnknownHostException: mysqldb
        at java.net.InetAddress.getAllByName0(InetAddress.java:1281) ~[na:1.8.0_191]
        at java.net.InetAddress.getAllByName(InetAddress.java:1193) ~[na:1.8.0_191]
        at java.net.InetAddress.getAllByName(InetAddress.java:1127) ~[na:1.8.0_191]
        at com.mysql.cj.protocol.StandardSocketFactory.connect(StandardSocketFactory.java:132) ~[mysql-connector-java-8.0.22.jar!/:8.0.22]
        at com.mysql.cj.protocol.a.NativeSocketConnection.connect(NativeSocketConnection.java:63) ~[mysql-connector-java-8.0.22.jar!/:8.0.22]
        ... 170 common frames omitted
```

However, when I change the spring.datasource.url inside **application.properties** to this:
`spring.datasource.url=jdbc:mysql://localhost:3307/exp?verifyServerCertificate=true&useSSL=false&serverTimezone=UTC&useLegacyDatetimeCode=false`
and build it it runs following exception:

```
The last packet sent successfully to the server was 0 milliseconds ago. The driver has not received any packets from the server.
        at com.mysql.cj.jdbc.exceptions.SQLError.createCommunicationsException(SQLError.java:174) ~[mysql-connector-java-8.0.22.jar!/:8.0.22]
```

And

```
Caused by: java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused (Connection refused)
        at java.net.PlainSocketImpl.socketConnect(Native Method) ~[na:1.8.0_191]
```

And

```
Caused by: javax.persistence.PersistenceException: [PersistenceUnit: default] Unable to build Hibernate SessionFactory; nested exception is org.hibernate.exception.JDBCConnectionException: Unable to open JDBC Connection for DDL execution
        at org.springframework.orm.jpa.AbstractEntityManagerFactoryBean.buildNativeEntityManagerFactory(AbstractEntityManagerFactoryBean.java:403) ~[spring-orm-5.2.10.RELEASE.jar!/:5.2.10.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.orm.jpa.AbstractEntityManagerFactoryBean.afterPropertiesSet(AbstractEntityManagerFactoryBean.java:378) ~[spring-orm-5.2.10.RELEASE.jar!/:5.2.10.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.orm.jpa.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean.afterPropertiesSet(LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean.java:341) ~[spring-orm-5.2.10.RELEASE.jar!/:5.2.10.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.invokeInitMethods(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1853) ~[spring-beans-5.2.10.RELEASE.jar!/:5.2.10.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1790) ~[spring-beans-5.2.10.RELEASE.jar!/:5.2.10.RELEASE]
        ... 135 common frames omitted
Caused by: org.hibernate.exception.JDBCConnectionException: Unable to open JDBC Connection for DDL execution
```

Comment: Have you tried using `--net spring-net` when starting mysqldb?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think it is too late to connect the mysql container to the same network as your spring container, so I would suggest you first create the network and use that in both of your containers.

```
$ docker network create my-network
```

Then you have to use the mysqldb container name and the inside port in your application.properties (because you are trying to connect from a container) like this:

```
spring.datasource.url=jdbc:mysql://mysqldb:3306/exp?verifyServerCertificate=true&useSSL=false&serverTimezone=UTC&useLegacyDatetimeCode=false
```